# how to solve error cannot communicate with CRS daemon?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, rac

I have oracle 10g 2 nodes RAC database ,
operating system HP UNIX
Electricity shut down 1 hour and database servers also shutdown after start the servers database not running and show the error when try to chech crs_stat -t

```
CRS-0184: cannot communicate with the CRS daemon
```

as you know there is no grid home in oracle 10g how to start the  CRS

```
crsctl start crs
```

I tried to run the command as root user but its not working and show message crsctl command not found

how to start the CRS in oracle 10g database RAC ?

Comment: "as you know there is no grid home in oracle 10g" It's been a while, but pretty sure 10g had a grid home when I last used it 15 years ago.

Comment: At some point there where these commands crs_stat, crs_start, crs_stop . Maybe /u01/app/10.2.0.4/grid/bin/crsctl stat res -t .

Comment: @BjarteBrandt what is the path of grid home I checked the following path I have /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2 and under this folder there is 2 folders asm and db_1 I tried to run the command under db_1 /bin crsctl check crs as root user and it show failure cannot communicate with CRS

Comment: cat /etc/oratab, there you should find the GRID_HOME for +ASM1. Set the environment: source oraenv <<< +ASM1 ; Fire: crsctl start crs; check clusterware log-files.